# Septoplasty in Vienna

Tags: health-insurance, austria, health, health-system

Don't know if this is the best place to ask this question, but if someone is an expat in Vienna and needs to do septoplasty (nasal septum deviation septoplasty), how he can find the right center and the right doctor for that? And what health insurance would cover that?

Comment: Have you checked with your existing health insurance provider?

Comment: @Traveller I am also looking to find a proper health insurance. I have a travel insurance, but I don't know if that cover septoplasty, or if pays right away.

Comment: AFAIK, health insurance doesn’t usually pay out to treat pre-existing conditions. Have you tried searching eg ‘health insurance for expats in Austria’? You should check your travel insurance T&C first