# Health insurance in Austria?

Tags: health-insurance, austria

I am going to be in Vienna, Austria for 4 months. I already have a travel insurance. What health insurance is good for me? I am not from a European country.

Comment: Highly depeeendent on your age and present health condition and thus not really answerable.

Comment: What research have you done up to now?

Comment: @Traveller I found this website: https://www.gesundheitskasse.at/cdscontent/?contentid=10007.835942&portal=oegkwportal  But since it is in German, I cannot get anything from it.

Comment: You seem to have posted two questions on pretty much the same topic https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/20074/septoplasty-in-vienna

Comment: @Traveller Same? No! One is about health insurance, the other is about finding a doctor or hospital.